# Shiny app datatable getting stuck in a loop when using DataTableProxy and a slow function

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I've got a Shiny app which outputs a datatable with selectable rows. When a row is clicked, this is captured and saved to a reactiveVals (`slct`). In my full app, checks are applied to the selected rows, and `dataTableProxy` is used to updated the selected rows in the table. Finally, a function is carried out to display a second table.

Unfortunately, when this function takes longer than the time between two clicks, the table gets stuck in a loop of selecting and unselecting the most recently clicked row.

I think this is happening due to the change not registering in time, and then the dataTableProxy loops, and iteratively applies both changes.

Minimal reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- function () {
  fluidPage(
    DTOutput("tbl"),
    DTOutput("tbl2")
  )
}

server <- function (input, output, session) {
  
  # initialise objects
  df = data.frame(a = 1:5)
  slct <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  # create DT and proxy
  output$tbl <- renderDT(df)
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("tbl")
  
  # update proxy and selection reactive, when rows are selected
  observe({
    rows <- input$tbl_rows_selected
    
    max_selected = 3
    if (length(rows) > max_selected) {
        # drop the second-last clicked row
        rows <- rows[c(1:(max_selected - 1), length(rows))]
    }
 
    slct(rows)
    DT::selectRows(proxy, rows)
  })
  
   # perform a slow function, then output the selected rows
  output$tbl2 <- renderDT({
    df_selected <- slow_function(df, slct)
    datatable(df_selected)
  })
}

slow_function <- function (df, slct) {
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  slice(df, slct())
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I've had this problem on previous apps as well, an as I can't find any information online, I was hoping someone would be able to help! The solutions I could think of are:

1. Disable either selections or the entire datatable while any processing is occurring
2. Find a way to identify if a loop is happening and prevent it
3. An actual fix to stop the datatable having this behaviour

But I can't come up with a good way to do any of these from my knowledge.

If it's relevant for any solutions, for the full app, the datatable also has the `RowReorder` extension enabled, with a JS callback, is setup in Shiny modules, and has `server=T` enabled.

Comment: Why are you selecting selected rows again (`DT::selectRows(proxy, rows)`)? This eventually refires your observer and you run into a race condition?

Comment: @thothal so in the full app I use this section to limit the number of selectable rows. I'll edit this into the reprex for context, was just trying to keep it as clean as possible!



In terms of why, originally it was because the only two solutions I found online to do the above were using JS callbacks (which I couldn't get to work due to interference with rowReorder, and a lack of JS knowledge, happy to explore that more though), and this solution.

Comment: @thothal actually in editing in your answer that got me thinking about just putting the reselect within that if statement, which seems to solve my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to @thothal's comment, I tried putting the `DT::selectRows` call within the relevant if statement (that originally wasn't in my question).

As far as I can tell, this now works because there is an end-case when the loop of updating rows will eventually end, because max_selected will drop low enough and therefore the statement won't be entered.

Updated code for the `observe`:

```
  observe({
    rows <- input$tbl_rows_selected
    
    max_selected = 3
    if (length(rows) > max_selected) {
      # drop the second-last clicked row
      rows <- rows[c(1:(max_selected - 1), length(rows))]
      DT::selectRows(proxy, rows)
    }
    
    slct(rows)
  })
```